# The Affine Tangent Cone

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm failing to see how exactly is the tangent cone at a singular point on a curve picking out all the different tangent lines through this singular point (say the origin in $\mathbb{A}^2$)?

Could someone explain this, or at least redirect me to a source I could read about? I tried to look online, but at most places they are just taking this as a known fact!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Initial remark.** Suppose someone gives you a continuous function of two variables, and asks you to calculate the Taylor series in $(0,0)$. If we happen to notice that the first derivatives vanish at the origin, we will call it a *critical point*.
The idea of the tangent cone is that we are doing exactly this: taking the Taylor series of the simplest continuous function: a polynomial. And if the first derivatives vanish, we call $(0,0)$ a *singular point*.

---

We have a curve $X=V(f)\subset \mathbb A^2$ passing through the origin.
Even if the origin is a nonsingular point of the curve, you do have a tangent cone at the origin: it is also called the *tangent line*! (and this is precisely encoded in the corresponding first terms of the "Taylor series" of $f$).

However, the tangent cone is constructed starting from the *leading form* of $f\in k[x,y]$, which is the homogeneous form $\tilde f$ of smallest degree appearing in the decomposition of $f$; it is again in two variables. For instance, the leading form of $f=2x+y-8y^2x$ is $\tilde f=2x+y$, the term of smallest degree. The tangent cone is the zero set $V(\tilde f)$. So the origin is nonsingular if and only if $f$ has leading form of degree one. In that case, $V(\tilde f)$ is exactly the tangent line.

In general, the leading form will be a product of linear factors, each appearing with some exponent. So the scheme $V(\tilde f)$ is a union of lines, where some of them are possibly nonreduced.

If $f$ starts, say, with degree $2$, then for instance $(0,0)$ will be a node in case the (degree $2$) leading form is a product of two distinct linear forms, i.e. something of the kind $$(ax+by)\cdot (cx+dy).$$ If, instead, the leading form has the shape $(ax+by)^2$, something else happens (example: the cusp $f=y^2-x^3$, whose tangent cone which is a double line).

---

Reference. All this is *beautifully* explained in Mumford's *The red book of varieties and schemes*.

Comment: I guess my question then $\bf{really}$ is how should I go about understanding that when I write $f=f_0+f_1+...+f_d$ where $f_i$ are homogeneous polynomials of degree $i$ in $x,y$, then why is the smallest such $f_r$ picking out all these different tangent lines at the singular point? Because, I think, I can see how it is working, I just don't seem to understand why. I'm not sure if I'm making sense? Thanks for the reference, by the way, I will definitely check that out!

Comment: You call them *tangents* because you are selecting the *least* degree in the homogeneous decomposition of $f$. You have them *all* just by definition (you take the *entire* homogeneous part). You actually *see* them one by one writing down the product decomposition of $\tilde f$ into linear factors. Sorry for being unclear on that.

Comment: My question might be more ignorant than I thought. Here is my confusion: Say that the leading form of $f$ factors into linear factors. Then, these two lines seem to be precisely the tangents at the singular point, of the two branches of $f$ respectively. For example take $f=y^2-x^2-x^3$. The leading form factors as $(x-y)(x+y)$ and these are precisely the tangent lines through the origin of the two branches of $f$. I don't see how this is happening in general. How are the other terms irrelevant? I might be missing something more fundamental.

Comment: It seems to me, like somehow we are writing $f$ as a product of some formal power series, and then these are defining each branch of $f$, and then in turn the linear term of these formal power series is representing the 'tangent' of the corresponding branch through this singular point of $f$. But, also, I'm not sure if we can always write $f$ as a product of these formal power series.

Comment: As for your first comment: I do not get what you mean when you say the other terms are "irrelevant". Also, I do not see power series hidden as factors of the polynomial $f$, but it is probably something I am missing myself. Indeed, the study of singularities is very much related to power series (maybe, those you mention), in particular to the *completions* of the local rings at the singular points. Sorry for not being able to say more on this.

Comment: As a concrete example, I reconsider the one in the previous comment: $f=y^2-x^2(x+1)=(y-x\sqrt{x+1})(y+x\sqrt{x+1})$, this factorization is valid over the completion of the local ring of $\{f=0\}$ around the origin. So, we can expand $\sqrt{x+1}$ in $\mathbb{C}[[x,y,]]$. This argument seems to hold in more generality. This is what i meant by the power series being hidden in the background. I talked to my professor today, and this seems to be a general result, with some restrictions. Then, the factors of $f$ (which are formal power series) give you the branches of $f$ around the singular point.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested I will write a reference for the 'answer' to this question: It turns out that this is a problem in Hartshorne, namely Problem 5.14 (b) of Chapter 1. I will write the statement here, and maybe at some point post a solution as well.

If $f=f_r+f_{r+1}+\cdots \in k[[ x, y]]$, and if the leading form $f_r$ factors as $f_r=g_sh_t$, where $g_s,h_t$ are homogeneous of degrees $s$ and $t$ respectively, and have no common linear factors, then there are formal power series 
$$g=g_s+g_{s+1}+\cdots$$
$$h=h_t+h_{t+1}+\cdots$$ in $k[[x,y]]$ such that $f=gh.$